# Where to know such keywords as EOF in Antlr4 language?

Tags: antlr4, lexer

I know Antlr4 has `EOF` keyword to denote end of file.

Where to see full list of such keywords?

I don't see `EOF` here: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md

Answer (score 3):

EOF is not a keyword but a token value. There are only very few such predefined valus and the best place to spot them is probably the source code. There is:

- EOF (the only predefined token value)
- DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL (the main channel to put tokens in)
- HIDDEN (the channel for hidden tokens, used often for whitespaces + comments).
- DEFAULT_MODE (the initial + main lexer mode)

Answer (score 2):

While, the free online documentation can be a bit sparse, the relevant section is [start-rules-and-eof](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#start-rules-and-eof).

Other resources include Parr's book [TDAR](https://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference) -- highly recommended, the [ANTLR4 grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/antlr4) itself, and the other sample grammars in that repo.

Comment: In TDAR book, is there a definition of all keywords like this in plain words? On which page?

Comment: In grammars from here https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/antlr4, where is the definition of EOF? Failed to find it at left hand side.

Answer (score 2):

All ANTLR reserved keyword names listed in [LexerATNFactory.java](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/4.6/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/automata/LexerATNFactory.java#L63) file.

Comment: Actually SKIP and MORE keywords are not used anywhere. But tokens can not have such identifiers.